# How to specify versions on PIP when installing a python package with it's dependencies

Tags: python, redis, pip, celery, django-celery

To install Celery with it's redis dependencies, one can do this.

```
$ pip install celery[redis]
```

Is it possible to explicitly provide version numbers to both celery and redis in the above command? It will effectively be the same as the following two commands

```
$ pip install -Iv redis==2.10.3
$ pip install -Iv celery==3.1.18
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify it with the flag `-Iv`

```
pip install -Iv redis==2.10.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `==`:

`pip install -Iv redis==2.10.3`

Comment: Use `pip uninstall redis` to unistall previous versions first, then do above